# Parse.com CloudCode to deliver a dynamic text file (for Webcal protocol)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

**The short story:**
Is there a way for Parse.com CloudCode  to return a text file from a url?

On Heroku I would use PHP or nodeJS. Is there a way to do so with cloud code?

**The long story:**
I've built a task manager (YATL ;-)) hosted on parse.com. Users have a "Today list" and they can schedule a time for their tasks. I want to export todays tasks (+their scheduled time) to Google Calendar using the Webcal protocol. I saw the webcal protocol is simply HTTP that sends an iCal text file (ics). Is there a way for me to create a unique url that invokes a CloudCode function with parameters to output a iCal ics file?

Pseudo example for such a URL:
webcal://todo.parseapp.com/cloudcode/getCalender/AQALYqbm60yAO3cD

Pseudo CloudCode output:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:19970610T172345Z-AF23B2@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970610T172345Z
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T040000Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the text content and then create a [`Parse.File`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.File.html) with it, then save the file and use the URL to return to the client.

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach however wouldnt the file be static. It is a calendar which changes according the data.

Comment: You would need to generate a new file (and clean up old ones) as things change